# Pasting (or merging) two elements of a column together

Tags: r, stack, paste, reshape

I have two sources of clinical procedure billing information that I have added together (with `rbind`). In each row there is a CPT field and a CPT.description field that supplys a brief explanation. However, the descriptions are slightly different from the two sources. I want to be able to combine them. That way, if different words or abbreviations are used, then I can just do a string search to find what I am looking for.

So lets make up a simplified representation of a data table that I was able to generate.

```
cpt <- c(23456,23456,10000,44555,44555)
description <- c("tonsillectomy","tonsillectomy in >12 year old","brain transplant","castration","orchidectomy")
cpt.desc <- data.frame(cpt,description)
```

And here is what I want to get to.

```
cpt.wanted <- c(23456,10000,44555)
description.wanted <- c("tonsillectomy; tonsillectomy in >12 year old","brain transplant","castration; orchidectomy")
cpt.desc.wanted <- data.frame(cpt.wanted,description.wanted)
```

I have tried using functions such as unstack and then lapply(list,paste) but that is not pasting the elements of each list. I also tried reshape but there was no categorical variable to differentiate first or second version of description or even in some cases a third. The really annoying part is I had a similar problem a few months or years ago and someone helped me either on stackoverflow or on r-help and for the life of me I cannot find it.

So the underlying problem is, imagine that I have a spreadsheet in front of me. I need to do a vertical merge (paste) of two or maybe even three description cells who have the same CPT code in the adjacent column.

What buzzwords should I have been using to search for a solution to this problem.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you're OK with commas instead of semicolons, you can just do `aggregate(description ~ cpt, cpt.desc, toString)`. Replace `aggregate` with your favorite aggregation tool, and replace `toString` with `paste` as described in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `plyr`.

```
library("plyr")
cpt.desc.wanted <- ddply(cpt.desc, .(cpt), summarise, 
  description.wanted = paste(unique(description), collapse="; "))
```

which gives

```
> cpt.desc.wanted
    cpt                           description.wanted
1 10000                             brain transplant
2 23456 tonsillectomy; tonsillectomy in >12 year old
3 44555                     castration; orchidectomy
```

Comment: I like this answer because it uses a package I already use a lot, and outputs the dataframe I want all with just one line of code that is easy to follow.

Comment: I thought the `, collapse="; "` argument of the `paste` function was optional. Why is it that in the syntax above it is necessary? Go ahead try to run the syntax without it. It will not work properly. Also if using data.table, `cpt.desc <- data.table(cpt,description)` one has to do this `cpt.desc[,list(desciption.wanted=paste(description, collapse="; ")),by=cpt]`

Comment: The `collapse` argument is optional, is as much as you don't have to specify it to be able to use the `paste()` function. But to do what you want to do, it is needed. `paste()` does two things. Given (potentially multiple) vectors as arguments, it combines them element-by-element into a single character vector (where the contributions from each vector are separated by `sep`). If `collapse` is not specified, this vector is returned. If `collapse` is specified, then the elements of the pasted together vector are themselves concatenated, separated by `collapse` and a single string is returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply( sapply(unique(cpt), function(x) grep(x, cpt) ),
                       # creates sets of index vectors as a list
        function(x) paste(description[x], collapse=";") )
       # ... and this pastes each set of selected items from "description" vector
[1] "tonsillectomy;tonsillectomy in >12 year old"
[2] "brain transplant"                           
[3] "castration;orchidectomy"
```

Comment: I like this answer because it uses only base functions.